# Excel: Extract unique values from column using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, formula, unique-values

I have a sheet in excel with a list of names, values and dates.

I'm trying to extract unique values from that list, but filtering them considering the "date" column first.

Image below is manually edited to show how it should work:

[image]

As of now, I'm able to extract unique values with this formula:

`{=INDEX($A$2:A:11,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($E$1:E1,$A$2:A:11),0))}`

After this, I'd use VLOOKUP for NAME and DATE, but using formula shown above extracts all values, and I'm trying to get values when DATE is less than 20/1/2018.

I tried adding "AND" formula, like: `AND(C2<=TODAY())` but that's not working for me...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a field validating `[Dates]` like `Filter` `=C2<TODAY()` and then using the field in a pivot table to filter your data:

[image]